# How to set minimum length of password

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I am currently working on a html form. How do I set the minimum length of the password to 8 so that it will reject any password the user inputs that are less than 8. How to do this?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="login-form">
            <form method="post">
            <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" name="btn-login">Sign In</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><a href="register.php">Sign Up Here</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 you can use the [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) and required attributes for the input tag:

```
<input type="password" pattern=".{8,}"   required title="8 characters minimum">
<input type="password" pattern=".{8,12}" required title="8 to 12 characters">
```

Also there is a [minlength](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes) attribute for input tags but it does not work in [some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength):

```
<input type="password" minlength="8" required>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pattern attribute:

```
<input pattern=".{8,}" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required />
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input type="Password" name="pd" placeholder="Password" pattern=".{8,16}" title="8 or more Character" size=30 pattern="[!@#$%^&*][a-z][A-Z][0-9]" required>
```

This code worked for me. Try this

Answer (score 2):

Change your button to :

```
<button name="btn-login">Sign In</button>
```

And add this code JavaScript (using jquery) :

```
$('button[name="btn-login"]').click(function() {
    if($('input[name="pass"]').val().length < 8) {
        alert('Minimum length = 8');
    } else {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Dont forget to add this condition into your PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `minlength` and `maxlength`

> As usual, you can use the minlength and maxlength attributes to
>   establish minimum and maximum acceptable lengths for the password.
>   This example expands on the previous one by specifying that the user's
>   PIN must be at least four and no more than eight digits. The size
>   attribute is used to ensure that the password entry control is eight
>   characters wide.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

[But it works on Chrome only at the moment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility)

Or, as someone already mentioned, you could use [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

> If your application has character set restrictions or any other
>   requirement for the actual content of the entered password, you can
>   use the pattern attribute to establish a regular expression to be used
>   to automatically ensure that your passwords meet those requirements.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

Comment: Hey, I've suggested an edit for your answer, take a look at that if you will. Also, maybe add an example of the usage of length and pattern.

Comment: As of 2021 all major browsers now support this tag: https://caniuse.com/input-minlength   It's only IE11 that is a real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the minimum length attribute is not supported by the all browsers. Please [check this out](http://caniuse.com/#search=minimum%20length)

Because of this, an alternate method has to used.

I've chosen the using of regex like the below;

```
<input type="password" name="pass" title="Password must be 8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and numeric characters" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" >
```

Comment: I don't think it is your responsibility to tell me how I choose to select a secure password for me. Oftentimes I don't sign up on sites that lay these kind of bricks in my way.

Comment: You're right. This code just a sample and still works in a production. So, if you want to use this code, you may need change the regex conditions according to your situation. Good luck.