# Html 5 Gives Alert: Please Match The Requested Format

Tags: php, html

This was working fine to set html input field's min & max char lengths:

```
<input type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' minlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' maxlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"'; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo " required>";} echo "<div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
```

I decided to shorten the "minlength=" and "maxlength=" by replacing them with:

pattern=".{18,2024}".

And so, I replaced my above mentioned code to:

```
<input pattern=' .'".{18,2084}" ' .'type=' .'"' .'text ' .'"' .'name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' minlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' maxlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"'; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo " required>";} echo "<div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
```

But why doesn't following amendment work ? It matches the above format of 'pattern=".{MIN INT,MAX INT}". '.

```
<input pattern='; echo '".' .$lengths .'"' .' type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"'; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "'required'>";} echo "<div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
```

And it doesn't work. Why ?
Whenever I input following into the url field, I get alert by html 5:
**Html 5 Gives Alert: Please Match The Requested Format!**

CONTEXT:
My html form has required inputs: Url, Anchor, Description.
Form labels are:

```
$form_inputs_labels_array = 
array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
```

Each input field has following minlength & maxlength input requirements:

```
$form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
$form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
```

Form Properties are:

```
$form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
$form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
```

The Html:

```
<form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="url">Url:</label>
        <input type="url" name="url" id="url" minlength="18" maxlength="2048" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        <label for="anchor">Anchor:</label>
        <input type="text" name="anchor" id="anchor" minlength="2" maxlength="40" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" minlength="13" maxlength="255" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>Search!</button><br>
    </form>
```

The Php Code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $form_types_array = array('register','login','signup','signin','submit','search');


if(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']))
{
    //WEBSITES->REGISTRATION/LOGIN FORM.
    if($_GET['type']=='register' OR $_GET['type']=='login')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("domain"=>"required","email"=>"required","password"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("domain"=>"5","email"=>"7","password"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("domain"=>"255","email"=>"255","password"=>"128");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("domain"=>"text","email"=>"email","password"=>"password");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("domain"=>"25","email"=>"25","password"=>"25");
        
        if($_GET['type']=='register')
        {
            $button_label = 'Register';
        }
        if($_GET['type']=='login')
        {
            $button_label = 'Log-in';
        }
    }
    //USERS->SIGNUP/SIGNIN FORM.
    elseif($_GET['type']=='signup' OR $_GET['type']=='signin')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("username"=>"required","email"=>"required","password"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("username"=>"8","email"=>"7","password"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("username"=>"40","email"=>"255","password"=>"128");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("username"=>"text","email"=>"email","password"=>"password");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("username"=>"25","email"=>"25","password"=>"25");
        
        if($_GET['type']=='signup')
        {
            $button_label = 'Sign-up';
        }
        if($_GET['type']=='signin')
        {
            $button_label = 'Sign-in';
        }
    }
    //WEBSITES->LINK SUBMISSION FORM.
    elseif(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='submit')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
        
        $button_label = 'Submit';
    }
    //LABELS->SEARCHERS->SEARCH FORM.
    if(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='search')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
        
        $button_label = 'Search';
    }
    else
    {
        die('Invalid Request!'); //Invalid Url. Invalid $_GET request.
    }
    
    $form_inputs_labels_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_labels_array);
    $form_inputs_labels_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_labels_array);
    
    $form_inputs_minlengths_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_minlengths_array);
    $form_inputs_minlengths_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_minlengths_array);
    
    $form_inputs_maxlengths_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_maxlengths_array);
    $form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_maxlengths_array);
    
    $form_inputs_types_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_types_array);
    $form_inputs_types_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_types_array);
    
    $form_inputs_sizes_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_sizes_array);
    $form_inputs_sizes_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_sizes_array);
}

if(EMPTY($_GET['type']) OR !in_array($_GET['type'],$form_types_array))
{
    die('Invalid Request!'); //Invalid Url. Invalid $_GET request.
}
else
{
    echo 
    "
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    $lengths = "$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[0],$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[0]";
    for($count=0;$count<$form_inputs_labels_count;$count++)
    {
        echo 
        "<label for=\"$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]\">"; echo ucfirst("$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]"); echo ':</label>
        <input type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' minlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' maxlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"'; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "'required'>";} echo "<div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        ";
    }
    echo 
    "
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    echo
    "
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>$button_label!</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";
}
?>
```

**More about the php page.**

The page shows html form type based on $_GET['type'] parameter. So, if the GET Param is register, then it will show a registration form. And, if the GET Param is login, then it will show a login form. And, if the GET Param is search, then it will show a search form. And so on.

For our example, the above mentioned html form I showed you was based on the GET Param is search.

Thank You.

**EDIT 1:**
**In short, I am replacing the long version that indicated the form input field's min & max lengths:**

```
minlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' maxlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count]
```

**with a short version:**

```
pattern=' .'".{18,2084}" '
```

**And so, it should work. Right ?**

EDIT 2:
I further amended my code to this:

```
if(EMPTY($_GET['type']) OR !in_array($_GET['type'],$form_types_array))
{
    die('Invalid Request!'); //Invalid Url. Invalid $_GET request.
}
else
{
    echo __LINE__; echo '<br>';
    echo 
    "
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    
    for($count=0;$count<$form_inputs_labels_count;$count++)
    {
        echo 
        "<label for=\"$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]\">"; echo ucfirst("$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]"); echo ':</label><br>';
        echo '<input pattern=' .'".' .'{' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[0] .',' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[0] .'}' .'"' .' type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"' .' title=' .'"' .'Min characters: '.$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[0] .',' .'Max characters: '.$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[0] .'" '; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "required><br>";}
        ;
    }
    echo 
    "
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    echo
    "
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>$button_label!</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";
}
```

Checking the source code, I see this as the html:

```
form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="url">Url:</label><br><input pattern=".{18,2048}" type="url" name="url" id="url" size="25" title="Min characters: 18,Max characters: 2048" required><br><label for="anchor">Anchor:</label><br><input pattern=".{18,2048}" type="text" name="anchor" id="anchor" size="25" title="Min characters: 18,Max characters: 2048" required><br><label for="description">Description:</label><br><input pattern=".{18,2048}" type="text" name="description" id="description" size="25" title="Min characters: 18,Max characters: 2048" required><br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>Search!</button><br>
    </form>
```

I get no other errors from browser.
I get error from browser if I make input below the set min or above the set max. I guess it's working now but I would appreciate if someone can confirm my this time amendment is bug free.

Comment: As far as I can see `$lengths` will never include the `{` and `}` which are present in your hard-coded version

Comment: @Adyson, How so ? On following question's first answer, I see the braces. I copied the code from there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084487/how-to-set-minimum-length-of-password

Comment: `How so?`...because it doesn't. Demo: https://3v4l.org/VQY1W . I can see that you've got the idea to use the braces, I understand that. but my point is that your code doesn't actually achieve that! You asked why it works when you hard-code it, and doesn't work when you replace it with your amendment, and the answer is because your `$lengths` variable doesn't contain the braces. You'll need to add them. Did it occur to you look at the raw HTML your PHP code was generating, to check it was outputting as you expected? If you did, you would hopefully have spotted this.

Comment: @Adyson, Yes, I did check the source code few hrs ago and managed to fix it. Kindly, check EDIT 2 section and confirm my current amended code is fine. Actually, I prefer you edit my code as your answer so I can go and accept your answer to give you a score/point.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work four different ways.
Check the comments TEST RESULT 1, TEST RESULT 2, TEST RESULT A and TEST RESULT B below.

1.

```
else
{
    echo __LINE__; echo '<br>';
    echo 
    "
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    for($count=0;$count<$form_inputs_labels_count;$count++)
    {
        echo 
        "<label for=\"$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]\">"; echo ucfirst("$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]"); echo ':</label><br>';
        //TEST RESULT 1: WORKING:
        echo '<input pattern=' .'".{$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count],$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count]}"' .' type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .$form_inputs_sizes_array_values[$count] .'"' .' title=' .'"' .'Min characters: '.$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .'Max characters: '.$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'" '; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "required><br>";}
        ;
        //TEST RESULT 2: ALSO WORKING: 
        //echo '<input pattern=' .'".' .'{' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'}' .'"' .' type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .$form_inputs_sizes_array_values[$count] .'"' .' title=' .'"' .'Min characters: '.$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .'Max characters: '.$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'" '; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "required><br>";}
    }
    echo 
    "
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    echo
    "
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>$button_label!</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";
}
```

2. 

```
else
{
    echo __LINE__; echo '<br>';
    echo 
    "
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    for($count=0;$count<$form_inputs_labels_count;$count++)
    {
        //input pattern=".{8,12}".
        //TEST RESULT A: WORKING:
        $input_lengths = '".{' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'}"';
        
        //TEST RESULT B: ALSO WORKING: 
        //$input_lengths = '"' .'.' .'{' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'}' .'"';
        
        echo 
        "<label for=\"$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]\">"; echo ucfirst("$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]"); echo ':</label><br>';
        echo '<input pattern=' .$input_lengths .' type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .$form_inputs_sizes_array_values[$count] .'"' .' title=' .'"' .'Min characters: '.$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .',' .'Max characters: '.$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'" '; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "required><br>";}
        ;
    }
    echo 
    "
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    echo
    "
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>$button_label!</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";
}
```